# NSRegularExpression Xcode warning: Unknown escape sequence '\]'

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, nsregularexpression

**I've received a Warning in Xcode:** `Unknown escape sequence '\]'`

**Code in Question:** `_regexForFindingTags = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"\[.*?\]" options:ops error:&error];`

**The Problematic Search Pattern:** `\[.*?\]`

Why is there a Warning for this Specific Search Pattern?
How can this Warning be Overcome?

My Search Pattern works in [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/) (granted that's in Javascript). According to [Ray Wenderlich's NSRegularExpression Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet) the `]` character should be escapable using the `\` character, So I'm missing something...

Comment: the code is not correctly formatted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get a warning from your compiler that is parsing string literal, not from regex engine. As escaping also exists for string literals, the sequence `@"\["` is just syntax error apart from regex' syntax (it is just string after all, right?). So, if original regex is `\[.*?\]`, it must be transformed it into:

```
[… initWithPattern:@"\\[.*?\\]" …];
```

I.e. you escape brackets at regex level and then also escape backslashes at string literal level, so `@"\\[.*?\\]"` becomes `\[.*?\]` in memory bytes.

Comment: Excellent! That was definitely it, of course I have to escape \ in order to use it in a String Literal!  :)

Answer (score 1):

You unfortunately need to escape the \
So they need to be \ in NSString literals